# table cell borders are not coming using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap "table-bordered" class for styling my table. Below is my table

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>column1head</td>
            <td>column2head</td>
            <td>column3head</td>
            <td>column4head</td>
            <td>column5head</td>
            <td>column6head</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form name="form1">
                <td>column1 label</td>
                <td>column2 label</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="row2column3chkbox"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="row2column4chkbox"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="row2column5txtbox"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="row2column6txtbox"></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form name="form2">
                <td>column1 label</td>
                <td>column2 label</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="row3column3chkbox"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="row3column4chkbox"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="row3column5txtbox"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="row3column6txtbox"></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <form name="form3">
                <td>column1 label</td>
                <td>column2 label</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="row4column3chkbox"></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" name="row4column4chkbox"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="row4column5txtbox"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="row4column6txtbox"></td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Each row is created dynamically and its td's are contained inside a form element. The problem here is from second row borders are not coming for each cell. Its working in Mozilla but not in IE9. how can make it work in all browsers.

**Demo:** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X9uHs/)

Comment: Looks fine in IE 11 to me.

Comment: You just said "IE". Lesson learned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, browsers like Chrome are treating the form around the cells as empty (that is, as not wrapping around the cells, but sitting just above them), and thus applying this rule:

```
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td
```

while IE9 needs this for it to work:

```
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > form > td
```

... because it sees the form as wrapping around the `td`s, which it should be doing. Not sure why Chrome et al. are seeing the form as not wrapping around those `td`s, but I wouldn't think this isn't a very good coding practice anyhow (although the validator doesn't seem to object to it).